# AES ECB known-text attack

Tags: c++, algorithm, encryption, aes

I'm trying to perform known-text attack to obtain 32 byte key.
BlockSize is 16 byte.

Regarding this: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/12512

Or this: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/102110

As far as I understood:

1) Encrypt known 15 byte block

2) Encrypt known 256 16 byte blocks with different tailing byte

3) Compare blocks and get one byte of secret

```
void test() {
    unsigned char KnownText[15];
    memset(KnownText, 'A', 15);

    unsigned char EncryptedText[32];
    int result_size = AES_ECB.EncryptBlock(EncryptedText, KnownText, 15);

    unsigned char CKnownText[16];
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
        memset(CKnownText, 'A', 16);
        CKnownText[15] = i;

        unsigned char Encrypted[32];
        int enc_result = AES_ECB.EncryptBlock(Encrypted, CKnownText, 16);

        if(memcmp(EncryptedText, Encrypted, 16) == 0) {
            //match found
        }
    }
}
```

I get only one match when i=0 (suppose because 0 was appended to first 15 byte block) and it is not even any of secret key bytes.

I can encrypt any length of any known data and get encrypted result.

How can I get the key using this attack?

Comment: If this is C, what is `BYTE`? A more conventional notation is `unsigned char` or `uint8_t`. Is that a type imposed by the AES library? Is this C++ code?

Comment: `BYTE` is `unsigned char`. I've already removed c++ tag because someone commented that it is more like c code. c++ or c does not really matters in this case. Anyway I've edited the code to be clearer.

Comment: It does matter if you're doing something like `AES_ECB.EncryptBlock(...)` which is really not a C thing. Also when using C++ you can use tools like `std::string` and `std::vector` instead of C-style byte arrays if that becomes relevant.

Comment: It could be C if i'm doing smth like `AES_ECB_EncryptBlock(...)` after all it is a function that just processing block.

Comment: _"...How can I get the key using this attack?_": The link is about finding the pre-appended secret (salt) not the encryption key.  Quote: _"If the server appends data that I control with a secret ... it is possible for me to figure out what the secret is..."_

Comment: You can write C-like code in C++ but that `AES_ECB` code won't compile unless it's C++. This is a C++ question since that's C++ code. This matters, so don't mis-tag. C++ is fine, it doesn't have to be C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EncryptBlock` probably does what it says is does: encrypt one block. The idea of the 15 byte first message is that you then *concatenate* the secret key block to it. I don't see where this happens (unless `EncryptBlock` is terribly badly named).

Currently the 16th byte that is encrypted is likely simply set to zero (using zero padding) by the `EncryptBlock` function. You may need to create a function that mimics what the server should do, including adding the server's secret to the initial message and possibly handle encrypting multiple blocks (assuming that the function doesn't already do this).

Note that this is **not** about retrieving the key from the block cipher, but retrieving a secret from the plaintext. This secret could have been added as some ill attempt to perform message authentication.

Comment: Seems `EncryptBlock` is badly named, it block-encrypts byte array of size. So if I pass size 32 or 48, it will produce encrypted byte array of `Size+(BlockSize-Size%BlockSize)+1` 2 or 3 encrypted blocks accordingly. This is not some kind of server-client encryption. Plain c++ project. I'm sure that i would need 2 or 3 known-text blocks to get the key as it is written in every ECB attack paper. But i'm stuck at trying to acomplish the first step - acquiring the first byte of the key as these guides says. Btw I've tried to encrypt 3-blocks array. It produce result as expected 3 same blocks.

Comment: Sorry, but in that case it does just perform ECB mode encryption with zero padding. So it will able to handle multiple blocks which is not what you expect from the function name. But still **there is no part where you add the two blocks holding the secret** and the method clearly doesn't add two blocks either. **So where do you add the secret to find to the ciphertext?** Currently you're just finding the zero padding, not the secret. And the zero padding is valued zero - which should not be *too* surprising.

Comment: Apparently I misunderstood the concept of attack which does not provide key recovery but just disclosure unknown ecrypted bytes with moving known encrypted blocks around. Is that it?

Comment: If you thought that you could retrieve the key of the block cipher through an ECB related attack then you were indeed thinking in the wrong direction. The key is protected by the block cipher, so it cannot be retrieved *regardless* of the mode of operation (ECB, CBC etc.). And your code doesn't try and recover the secret either, because it never puts the secret into the plaintext message. Hint: when trying to simulate two parties, then *program* two parties.